# Phylogentic Footprinting Project

Tags: dna

I'm working on performing phylogentic footprinting to figure out how many TRE sequences there are in the TWIST1 gene. (Sequence motifs). I'm trying to use ENSEMBL to gather orthologues of species in which the gene twist1 is present, compile it into a FASTA file and upload it to MEME SUITE. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to compile the file. I also don't know how to read SEQUENCE LOGOS. If anyone can help me, I would appreciate it SOOOOO much.

Comment: Can you post an image of your logos? Its easier to explain then.